# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError when executing simultaneous inserts

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following implementation of an insert (one to many relationship)

Assume that i have a `session` object yielded and the `data_model.py` available.

```py
with session.begin():
    song = data_model.Songs(name="Bad Medicine", duration_in_seconds=316)
    singer = session.scalar(
                select(data_model.Singers).where(
                    data_model.Singers.name == "Bon Jovi"
                )
             )

    if singer is None:
         singer = data_model.Singers(name="Bon Jovi")
         session.add(singer)

    # append the relationship
    singer.songs.append(song)
```

When you exit the context manager, the commit is done automatically.

So far, all good. This runs on a single container as a webserver in a particular endpoint, that is accepting max 1 connection.

Then, I scale this service to 2 instances and I get the following issue.

Service 1 tried to find "Bon Jovi" in the table, it was not there, and adds it to the session but by the time its commit occurs, service 2 (which also tried to write a Bon Jovi song) has already committed, so now Service 1 encounters an exception (IntegrityError), because it tried to add a record that is already there.

How can I address this kind of condition? I want to stay away of "retry" solutions as much as possible.

The database I m using is Postgres 15 and SQLAlchemy 2.0.19.

Comment: If you don’t want to handle this using retry mechanisms, you can try using a unique constraint and exception handling to ensure that your insertions does not cause integrity violations